# Can I retrieve list of developers/apps from an org on Apigee edge based on a custom attribute?

Tags: apigee

Is it possible to get list of developers or apps from an org on Apigee platform based on a chosen custom attribute?

Answer (score 5):

At this point in time, you cannot query for developers or apps based on custom attributes. The best you can do is GET them all and filter out those that do not match.

You can, however, get all apps or developers in the same payload, and then use XPath or JSONPath to find the matches, which will reduce your work.

```
GET https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/{org}/developers?expand=true
GET https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/{org}/apps?expand=true
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no direct way to selectively get a list of developers/apps. But you can write a simple script to iterate over the developers/apps and get the details based on condition/custom attribute.